# Difference between "per" and "a"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> She goes to the forest three times **per** week.
>
> She goes to the forest three times **a** week.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*A* in that sense is a preposition meaning the same thing as *per*.  Any dictionary will have that as a definition for *a* ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a)):

> ***preposition***
>   each; every; per: *ten cents a sheet; three times a day.*

[Oxford Dictionary Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a?region=us) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a) have similar entries.

So there is no difference in meaning between your examples.  As to usage differences, *per* is characterized as being more formal and careful, so you would see it more in academic or legal writing or precise instructions, while *a* would be more common in speech and normal writing.

Comment: OED says " b. With adverbs of repetition (as once, twice, many times, oft a day); now classified as the indefinite article". So perhaps we can say that historically this usage of *a* was as a preposition, but that it is increasingly being analyzed as a determiner.

Comment: @Brett, Mark: My (slightly out-of-date) OED says under "**per** *prep,*" Section III 2 a *In distributive sense, following words of number or quantity in expressions denoting rate or proportion: For each…, for every…: = a prep.1 8 b, by prep. 24 c. See also per cent, cent1 2.*

Comment: There is an archaic preposition that is now is chiefly a member of compounds (e.g., abroad, abreast, adrift, afloat, ashore, etc.). As I've commented elsewhere, you can replace the determiner *a* with a variety of other determiners, and there would be no motivation to say that they are prepositions too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The OED says, "b. With adverbs of repetition (as once, twice, many times, oft a day); **now classified as the indefinite article**: see a adj. 4".

Comment: @Brett Reynolds: I don't doubt it. The way we commonly use the word has perhaps shifted a bit over recent years too. I was just making the point that even OED has had different opinions in the past. Calling it preposition isn't ridiculous. Whatever - they're just convenient pigeonholes to put things in. It's not like they're pre-existing template classes, giving rise to the forms we end up using.

Comment: I did go overboard saying that it was nonsense. I should have looked at the history of the analysis before reacting. Given the pattern of the other determiners in the same positions, though, doesn't the determiner analysis strike you as more consistent and reasonable than the preposition analysis?

Comment: @Brett Reynolds: Yes, I think the change was probably sensible. But like I said, *usage* has shifted anyway. And my OED calls *each* and *every* for example, "quasi-pronouns". In some contexts they're interchangeable with *per*, sometimes only with each other, and sometimes not even that. "Part of speech" categories are something of a blunt instrument when you get down to the details.

Comment: The OED has only recently begun using the DET label and hasn't completed its revisions. Unfortunately, they chose to add it as extra information while continuing to label words as adjectives, pronouns, etc. As for "part of speech" being a blunt instrument, it becomes much sharper when it's used more rigorously.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking, *"per"* and *"a"* are equivalent in OP's examples (effectively, meaning *"in each"*, or *"in every"*), but it's worth pointing out that using *"per"* like this has overtones of science/academia, business/commerce jargon, legalese, etc., often implying a "commitment to accuracy".

Thus we wouldn't be surprised to discover that she [(Little Red Riding Hood?)](http://ivyjoy.com/fables/redridinghood.html) *usually* goes to the forest three times **a week** as a casual activity of her own choice (to pick flowers or whatever), where it's quite possible she actually goes twice or four times some weeks.

But if we're told she goes three times **per week**, that suggests a more formal arrangement. Perhaps because Granny will be taken into care if the family can't keep up a regular schedule of home visits to make sure she gets enough cake to eat, for example.

Answer (score 2):

They are both right,  but *[a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a)* is more common.

***[per](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per)*** (preposition)

> : with respect to every member of a specified group : for each

***[a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a)*** (preposition)

> : in, to, or for each

Comment: More common, maybe.  But try writing in your physics paper "25 centimetres a second".

Answer (score 2):

In general usage, the first **feels** more precise than the second. The former implies each and every week she goes to the forest exactly three times. The latter has a more general feeling - she goes to the forest about three times of the week, depending on the weather and her moods. As always, context is probably more important than the exact grammar in determining the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a grammatical difference, in that *per* is a preposition followed by a noun phrase without a determiner. In the second sentence, *a week* is a typical noun phrase. Despite these grammatical differences, the standard interpretation of each sentence would be the same.

Comment: Believe it or not, "a" is usually [regarded as a preposition in those circumstances](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a#Etymology_3_2), and that particular "a" arose from the preposition "on".

Comment: Nonsense! Wiktionary has this wrong. There is a preposition *a*, but it has absolutely nothing to do with this. It's a straight determiner, and can be replaced by other determiners (e.g., *two times this week, two times each week, two times some weeks,* etc.)

Comment: Then [the Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a&allowed_in_frame=0) has it wrong too. And so does the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8?rskey=dYJfy0&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid). Admittedly the OED does include a note for this sense, "now classified as the indefinite article", so it's open to some analysis. But it's certainly not "Nonsense!"

Comment: The OED says, "b. With adverbs of repetition (as once, twice, many times, oft a day); **now classified as the indefinite article**: see a adj. 4" because the previous analysis was clearly wrong.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: I apologize for the tone of the reaction.

Answer (score -2):

When referring to people I would tend to use *per*, e.g. 24€ per person, or 24 kilos per passenger.

Answer (score -4):

Ditto Brett. I think the "a week" is simply wrong as the word "week" has no clear role in the sentence. I think people who say this are either contracting "per" to "a", or they are ommiting a preposition, like "three time IN a week".

Comment: See my comment to Brett - "a week" and similar forms are well-established in English, and came from abbreviation of the preposition "on".

Comment: It is perfectly normal for noun phrases to function as adjuncts (or what school grammar bizarrely likes to call "adverb phrases"). It happens all over the place: *this week, I'm going; I was paid twice this week,* etc. That's what's happening with *a week.* It's not wrong and it has nothing to do with prepositions.

Comment: [Christmas Comes But Once a Year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Comes_But_Once_a_Year). Or should that be *"once **in** a year"*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Headlines and titles are not generally the best models for good grammar.

Comment: @BrettReynolds Hmm, but in "I'm going this week", "this week" acts as an adverb saying when you are going. But in "goes three times a week", I don't see any relationship established between "a week" and either "goes" or "three times".

Comment: @Jay: I can't say I remember for sure (it *was* over 3 years ago, after all! :) but I think at the time I didn't realise all three Wikipedia pages for [*Christmas Comes But Once a Year*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Christmas+Comes+But+Once+a+Year%22#q=%22Christmas+Comes+But+Once+a+Year%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899) (including mine in that earlier link) were *titles* (of a film, a radio play, and a TV episode). But my link in *this* comment is to a shedload of C19 written instances (when it certainly *was* "good grammar" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, it was a while ago. The question just showed up with a new comment or a vote or something.

Comment: Jay: Noting one of the examples in @Daniel's answer, I think you'd have a hard time convincing most people that *Take two tablets three times a day* was in any meaningful sense "short for" an underlying *...three times **in** a day.* Realistically, including ***in*** there would be so unusual syntactically that I'd feel compelled to look for an unusual *meaning* (perhaps that you only take the medicine for a maximum of 24 hours, I dunno). So I think you should seriously consider either deleting this answer, or finding some additional support for the position (if you still hold it! :)